# Initiliaze assiocations on Opportunity made from Lead

Tags: while-loop, insert, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

On a Lead it is possible to insert Associations, when I qualify a Lead, a Opportunity is made, which shows Associations lines.

I want to insert the associations from the Lead into the opportunity in AX2012.

I have found out the associations in the Lead is using the `smmLeadRelTable`, the Opportunity is using the `smmOpportunityRelTable`.

How can i insert the association? I don't see the relation between these tables and I can't figure how to start to initialize these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `smmLeadRelTable` as well as the `smmOpportunityRelTable` table references leads and opportunities using the RefTableId/RefRecId pattern. This pattern allows for generic references in cases where it is not clear at design time what tables will be referenced or where a number of different tables should be referenced. To create a reference, you would initialize the `RefTableId` field with the id of the table that is to be referenced. You would then initialize the `RefRecId` with the RecId of the record from that table that is to be referenced.

To fulfill your requirement you want to transfer the entries in `smmLeadRelTable` to `smmOpportunityRelTable`, replacing the `LeadId` with the `OpportunityId`. The entries in `smmOpportunityRelTable` are created in method `createLinkRelation` in class `smmCreateEntity`. There you could add an [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg839762.aspx) or edit the method directly to add your logic that will create an entry in `smmOpportunityRelTable` for each opportunity relation in `smmLeadRelTable`.